# Are questions about literature in this site's scope?

Tags: discussion

Can we ask questions that are a little more theoretical, about where to found scientific articles, or about literature in information security? Will they be  accepted by the community?

I would like ask about a repository of content concerning security information,  but before I do, I need ask at meta, if it is part of the scope.

Comment: What @Schroeder said below. However I would point out that such questions have been asked long ago (before we blocked them), some of those answers will still be good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Questions about where to find products, resources, or links are off-topic. Because the accepted answer will end up being a single URL that may or may not survive.